# How to list only paths via CMD

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to list paths to all files with specific extension on my hard drive.

I am using `dir *.txt /s /b` and this is my output:

```
C:\Path\To\File\1.txt
C:\Path\To\File\2.txt
C:\Path\To\File\3.txt
C:\Path2\To\File\1.txt
```

But instead of that I need only paths to those files, without duplicates and filenames. So in that cast it would be:

```
C:\Path\To\File\
C:\Path2\To\File\
```

any help welcome

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A batch file processed by the Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` for listing all directories containing at least one file with file extension `.txt` on system drive is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "PreviousDirectory="
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir %SystemDrive%\*.txt /A-D-L /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    set "CurrentDirectory=%%~dpI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if not "!PreviousDirectory!" == "!CurrentDirectory!" (
        endlocal
        echo %%~dpI
        set "PreviousDirectory=%%~dpI"
    ) else endlocal
)
endlocal
```

There is started one more command process in background to run the command **DIR** of which output is captured by the command process which is processing the batch file. It can take for that reason several seconds or even minutes before any output is displayed at all as there is first searched the entire system drive for all files with file extension `.txt` not being a link before the list of file names is processed by command **FOR**.

There could be used also a batch file with the following command lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if exist "%SystemDrive%\*.txt" echo %SystemDrive%\
for /D /R "%SystemDrive%\" %%I in (*) do if exist "%%I\*.txt" echo %%I\
endlocal
```

That outputs the directory paths while searching through the entire system drive. But it can result in false positives if a directory contains a directory or a link ending with `.txt` in name. This solution does also not output directories with hidden attribute set containing a file with file extension `.txt`. The first solution is therefore better.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I will analyze what exactly is going on here. Thanks for the effort you put into the answer.